# EnhanceIO Telegraf `filestat` plugin - Super GLOB pattern not working - Make telegraf recursively look for all files

Tags: wavefront, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-plugins, wavefront-telegraf

**Telegraf v1.0.1** (*git: master 26acdc9231efde105510fe5df3da7519bc4f42f7*)

Telegraf service is running successfully `sudo service telegraf status` shows `telegraf is running [OK]`.

I'm using Wavefront's SaaS based monitoring solution for showing Telegraf data or setting up various other things (alerts, dashboards).. it works.

**Overview**: 
When you install Telegraf, it creates its main config file at */etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf* and a user can put other configurations under **/etc/telegraf/telegraf.d**/*.conf (files).

I have */etc/telegraf/telegraf.d/extra-inputs-plugins.conf* and in this file, I have the following contents (as you see, it's using [filestat inputs plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/filestat)) and the following configuration works:

```
## Telegraf filestat plugin
[[inputs.filestat]]
  files = ["/var/run/*/*.pid","/var/run/*.pid"]
```

On some database servers, I have installed `EnhanceIO` (for more info look here: https://github.com/stec-inc/EnhanceIO

Once EnhanceIO is installed, you'll get a folder structure like this:

```
ubuntu@MyTestCluster-1a-db2-i-0cf6u98b136b211ba:~$ find /proc/enhanceio
/proc/enhanceio
/proc/enhanceio/data_cache
/proc/enhanceio/data_cache/config
/proc/enhanceio/data_cache/io_hist
/proc/enhanceio/data_cache/errors
/proc/enhanceio/data_cache/stats
/proc/enhanceio/version
```

To configure Telegraf's **filestat** plugin to catch/look for `/proc/enhanceio/data_cache/config` file, I can add that or `/proc/enhanceio/data_cache/*` in my configuration (but doing this way, the solution won't be scalable i.e. what if I want telegraf to pick all files under **/proc** folder.

The plugin doc / comments section says:

```
  ## These accept standard unix glob matching rules, but with the addition of
  ## ** as a "super asterisk".
```

So, I tried the following configuration to look for every file (recursively):

```
[[inputs.filestat]]
  files = ["/var/run/*/*.pid","/var/run/*.pid","/proc/*"]
```

The above resulted in the following output when I run: `$ telegraf --config-directory=/etc/telegraf -test|grep filestat|grep -v '/var/run/'|grep enhance` (actually /proc/enhanceio is a folder).

```
> filestat,host=MyTestCluster-1a-db2-i-0cf6u98b136b211ba,file=/proc/enhanceio exists=1i,size_bytes=0i 1485548956000000000
```

Then, I tried using the `**` approach but I got **NOTHING**?

```
[[inputs.filestat]]
  files = ["/var/run/*/*.pid","/var/run/*.pid","/proc/**"]

$ telegraf --config-directory=/etc/telegraf -test|grep filestat|grep -v '/var/run/'|grep enhance
2017/01/27 20:31:38 I! Using config file: /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
$
```

I tried, almost all **glob** patterns (like: `/proc/enhanceio/*/*`, `/proc/enhanceio/*/**`, `/proc/enhanceio/**/*` or `/proc/enhanceio/**/**`) but it just didn't catch any files under /proc/enhanceio tree.

**Why filestat plugin's SUPER GLOB pattern didn't work at all when I tried the above patterns?**

**How can I make the filestat plugin catch all files under /proc tree?**

**PS**: I know giving `/proc/enhanceio/data_cache/*` will work if I want to catch `config` file under that directory (at just that level).

Comment: Please open a [feature request](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/new) on the Telegraf repository for this issue.

Comment: This is what I got from Cameron Sparr: `/proc is a very special "filesystem" that is actually a "file" mapping to particular kernel parameters and metrics. Glob and path matching may not work in this area as you might expect.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Cameron Sparr's comment and testing on this, she couldn't reproduce the above situation with the following example but the examples I mentioned in my post were valid as well in not catching the super glob patterns.

Per her comment, it seems like: `/proc is a very special "filesystem" that is actually a "file" mapping to particular kernel parameters and metrics. Glob and path matching may not work in this area as you might expect.`

```
% ls -R /tmp/test
/tmp/test:
enhance/  foo.log

/tmp/test/enhance:
bar.log  nested/

/tmp/test/enhance/nested:
foo.file
then with this config:

[[inputs.filestat]]
  files = ["/tmp/test/**.log", "/tmp/test/**.file"]
  ## If true, read the entire file and calculate an md5 checksum.
  md5 = false
I was able to find all files

% telegraf --config ~/gd/ws/telegraf.conf --input-filter filestat --output-filter discard --test
* Plugin: inputs.filestat, Collection 1
> filestat,file=/tmp/test/enhance/bar.log,host=tyrion size_bytes=4i,exists=1i 1485988684000000000
> filestat,file=/tmp/test/foo.log,host=tyrion size_bytes=0i,exists=1i 1485988684000000000
> filestat,file=/tmp/test/enhance/nested/foo.file,host=tyrion exists=1i,size_bytes=0i 1485988684000000000
```